# Want to search from database ignoring the white spaces from the content

Tags: mysql

I want to search a key '**unconscious of its own Self**' from database. Where as in database the content is present in this form::

**it. The twine itself is in illusion because it finds itself bound by knots.**

**The knots are the sanskaras and the twine is the soul. Because the soul is unconscious**

**of its own Self as God, its attention remains focussed on the knots. To be freed**

I have used the following sql query to fetch my result:

```
SELECT f.content FROM file_details f WHERE REPLACE(f.content, ' ', '') = REPLACE("unconscious of its own Self", ' ', '');
```

No such record found. Reason why is that so is, sql function REPLACE(f.content, ' ', '') converted my content in following format::

```
"it.Thetwineitselfisinillusionbecauseitfindsitselfboundbyknots.
Theknotsarethesanskarasandthetwineisthesoul.Becausethesoulisunconscious
ofitsownSelfasGod,itsattentionremainsfocussedontheknots.Tobefreed"
```

If you see my search key after replace 'unconsciousofitsownSelf' in the content above you will find that in two separate lines. That is why I have got result as 0.

Can you please provide me a solution for this to search my key which is even present in separate lines.

Comment: Your source text looks pretty nasty, I'd fix that before even attempting a query.  Also, it seems that line breaks are what you really need to be removing anyway.

Comment: The content in database is some thing which I can not modify. Can we still do the search without making the modification in the database and that too using MYSQL only.

Comment: Question: Is all formatting sensible besides the line breaks?  To be specific, if we remove the line breaks would we be left with the text `unconscious of its own Self` ?  Or, are there other whitespace problems introduced by the line breaks?

Comment: Yes, The only problem which I am facing here is due to the Line break once it is removed I will get the result I am expecting.

Comment: How will the text be equal even after removing spaces or new line characters? You are comparing the substring as exact equal to that of main string.

Comment: Try the comment by @spencer7593 and see if you can match what you need.  Again, hopefully these line breaks are the extent of change to the whitespace.

Comment: Yeah - some missing commas there

Comment: `REPLACE( REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE( f.content ,'\n',''),'\r',''),'\t','') ,' ','')`   replace all newline characters and tabs, as well as spaces

Comment: @Tim I used following two queries and now my search engine is working perfectly

UPDATE file_details f set f.content = REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( f.content, '  ', ' ' ), '  ', ' ' ), '  ', ' ');

UPDATE file_details f set f.content = REPLACE( REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE( f.content ,'\n',' ') ,'\r','') ,'\t','') ,'  ',' ');

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Searching if this word `"unconscious of its own Self"` exists in your database:

```
set @sam = "it. The twine itself is in illusion because it finds itself bound by knots.
The knots are the sanskaras and the twine is the soul. Because the soul is unconscious
of its own Self as God, its attention remains focussed on the knots. To be freed";


select  case when rplace like '%52521325241%' then 'found' else 'not found' end) from 
(SELECT SOUNDEX(@sam) rplace) as a
```

or here's the second option:

```
select case when rplace like concat('%',searchChar,'%') then 'found' else 'not found' end,searchChar from
(select SUBSTRING(SOUNDEX('unconscious of its own Self'),2) as searchChar,rplace from 
(SELECT SOUNDEX(@sam) rplace) as a) as b;
```